# Lubuntu 20.04 LTS: Some accent characters not working

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, 20.04

Recently, I've updated my laptop from Lubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 LTS.
Ever since then, wherever in the OS (be it FeatherPad, Qterminal, Writer...), one of my accents (ˇ) is broken - the system types `r` instead of `ř` when pressing `ˇ` followed by `r`. I've seen many posts online about accent keys being broken, but the solutions didn't work for me.

I'm using Slovak QWERTZ keyboard layout. I've tried installing iBus (and removing it again), uninstalling Fcitx and fiddling with my system settings. Nothing worked, and QTerminal, FeatherPad and LibreOffice still refuse to accent my letters.

The accent works in Firefox and Discord though, for some reason. And it's only the `ˇ` accent that's broken - all other accents work.

Is there any fix for this? Thanks for your help in advance!